# Microsoft WebView2 evergreen standalone runtime not working

Tags: delphi, webview2

Accordingly to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#understanding-the-webview2-runtime

It is supposedly okay having users download/install "The Evergreen Standalone Installer":
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section

If using this solution, I found the actual installed paths for the DLLs are:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeCore\95.0.1020.40\EBWebView\x64\EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeCore\95.0.1020.40\EBWebView\x86\EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\95.0.1020.40\EBWebView\x64\EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\95.0.1020.40\EBWebView\x86\EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll
```

(with version number matching whatever version user downloaded from the above page)

This is fine, I can scan for this and select newest...

But trying to load these fails because
"CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions" is not found... (Unlike if you use "WebView2Loader.dll")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Opinion based questions are most likely closed.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: @AmigoJack I have removed the part where I ask for opinion on if bad to use the evergreen installer. The main question still stands.

Comment: You need both "WebView2Loader.dll" and the runtime. "WebView2Loader.dll" comes from the WebView2 you install in your program and is needed to even compile your app, while the runtime is needed to run the app.

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you. I realized, so I ended up getting it working. (I load the loader dll at runtime.) I had originally figured "evergreen" would more resemble widodws API and not require a separate loader DLL but I was wrong in that assumption :)